# How to create a Kubernetes cluster with 3 MariaDB database engines that can take client connections while in sync with each other?

Tags: kubernetes, mariadb

I am currently embarking on a project within the field of ***Technology Solutions for Financial Markets*** that requires the deployment of a MariaDB database cluster within a Kubernetes environment. My goal is to establish a cluster consisting of three MariaDB database engines. Here are the key requirements:

1. All database instances ***must be synchronized***, ensuring data
   consistency across the cluster.
2. The setup should robustly handle client connections for `SELECT`, `INSERT`, and `DELETE` queries.
3. In case one of the database engines becomes unavailable, client
   connections should automatically reroute to **1** of the remaining
   operational instances.

I have chosen Kubernetes for deployment due to its scalability and management features. However, I'm facing challenges in configuring the MariaDB cluster to meet these specific requirements, especially in terms of data synchronization and failover management.

*Could anyone provide guidance and share examples of Kubernetes `YAML` configuration files that might fit this scenario?*

Additionally, any insights or best practices regarding this type of setup would be immensely valuable. I am looking for a solution or advice that can lead me to a robust and efficient implementation.

Your expertise and experience in this area would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are both dedicated [devops.se] and [dba.se] sites, as well as [sf] for system-administration questions.  Stack Overflow is more specifically for programming-related questions, and one of these other sites might be a more appropriate place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at `mariadb-operator`:
https://github.com/mariadb-operator/mariadb-operator

It pretty much covers what you mentioned above. The [README.md](https://github.com/mariadb-operator/mariadb-operator/blob/main/README.md) is the best starting point

Let me know if you have any questions and feel free to open an issue if something doesn't work as expected.